# If a data frame contains a column whose members have different classes, how do I filter out the rows based on their class?

Tags: r

This question is a bit difficult for me to ask because I am encountering it in a large dataset with spatial data which was given to me and I cannot post it here. In this data, one of the columns contains the geometry of spatial objects which differ in their classes, e.g. some are `POLYGON`, some are `LINE` etc. However, these attributes are not the only class that they have, they often have also `sfg` or `sfc`. So they are multiclass objects, and the same column contains objects of different classes.

I wanted to create some toy minimal example, but I don't know how to do it, because I can't find a way to set custom classes to rows in a data frame.

Therefore, the question is composed of two parts. In the first part I will post my code for creating example toy data, which doesn't work, but I think that the logic behind it will be quite easy to grasp and I am hoping that someone will be able to correct my code and create the example data.

In the second part, I will post the actual question.

***First part:***

```
a <- 1:5
b <- 6:10

df <- data.frame(a, b)

class(df$b[1]) <- c("X", "Y")
class(df$b[2]) <- c("X", "Z")
class(df$b[3]) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
class(df$b[4]) <- c("Z", "Y")
class(df$b[5]) <- c("Y")
```

This doesn't work because if we call for example `class(df$b[1])` it will give us `integer` instead of `c("X", "Y")`. But let's imagine that it did work, because that's what my data looks like.

***Second part***

I want to filter out just the cases where `b` possesses a class of `Y`. I was trying to use the following code:

```
df %>% 
  filter("Y" %in% class(b))
```

But it doesn't work. In my real dataset, I just get an empty dataframe back. It seems to me that `class(b)` inside of `filter` assesses the class of the whole `b` column instad of its individual members and therefore fails. But I don't know a way to change it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably do some reading about [list columns in data frames](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls13_list-columns.html), as that's the only way I know of to have elements with different classes in the same column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `%in% class()` should work, but `inherits` is a generally recommended way to test whether an object inherits from a particular class, e.g., `inherits(b, "Y")`. But as only lists can have items of different classes, you'll need to apply `inherits` to each list element. I would think `df %>% filter(sapply(b, inherits, "Y"))`.

Here's my attempt at a reproducible example:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:3)
df[["b"]] = list(1, 2, 3)

class(df$b[[1]]) = "X"
class(df$b[[2]]) = c("X", "Y")
class(df$b[[3]]) = "Y"

df %>% filter(sapply(b, inherits, "Y"))  
#   a b
# 1 2 2
# 2 3 3
```